# How to bind an array to ngModel in angular and detect the changes

Tags: angular

I have an array of strings

```
array = ["one","two","three","four"]
```

, 
I want to bind this values to some input like this:

```
<input class="form-control"
                       type="text"
                       [(ngModel)]="array">
```

Then when user changes something in the input, for example adds "five" i would like to add it to array, the same with removing. 
I have done it like I showed earlier, and at first the input has array[4], but when I start typing something in the input Angular changes it to string one,two,three,four,five
How can I do this binding to just update the original array without converting it to string?

Comment: You can't, at least not with `input type="text"`. You could try to create your own control but you need to find a way to display a way to interact with your array. Often times you want to restrict the options to a list and allow the user to select multiple items from the list which then are bound to an array. This is very common. Without more information from you though it is not clear what it is you are looking for exactly.

Comment: Basically, I'm looking for a way to make an input where user can write whatever he wants, and the text he will write will be added to the array of strings.

Comment: You will have to do some work on your end to make that possible. You could use `(change)="inputChanged($event);` and then do the work there.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't bind a array with text input field

2) Trigger an event when value changes in text field

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  (change)="add($event.target.value)">
```

3) On function just add that value in array

```
add(value){
    this.array.push(value)
    console.log(this.array)
  }
```

**.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  array = ["one","two","three","four"]

  add(value){
    this.array.push(value)
    console.log(this.array)
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text"  (change)="add($event.target.value)">
```